# How to move partitions safely

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, gparted

I have Ubuntu and Windows in a dual boot configuration and now I want to resize the Ubuntu partition in order to allocate more space to the Windows one.

[image]

As you can see, I have unallocated space at the end, that I got from /dev/sda7 (Ubuntu /home partition). After some attempts in Gparted (I didn't apply anything!), I realized it's possible to get unallocated space immediatly after Windows partition (/dev/sda4), because, as I said before, it's the partition I want to resize.
Now, beacuse of this operation, the two Linux partitions (/dev/sda6 and /dev/sda7) would change position and in fact Gparted notified me about the fact that I could not be able to boot anymore!
The question is: is there a fix I could immediatly apply after I do these operations in order to continue to boot successfully?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this enitre conversation and all comments have been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52140/discussion-on-question-by-generoso-how-to-move-partitions-safely).

Answer (score 2):

From the comments...

To answer your question, if you need to, you can either reinstall GRUB, or use `Boot Repair` to repair a non-bootable situation. See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair for detailed information. Search here on AU for `Boot Repair` and you'll get plenty of info. You'll need a bootable Ubuntu Live DVD to do this.

The gparted warning about moving partitions and becoming unbootable mostly applies to Windows partitions. Windows is very fussy about where its partition is on the disk, and doesn't like external changes to that position.

**Make backups before any moves!**

In moving/resizing partitions, **use gparted to move sda5/6/7 to the right, and use Windows Disk Management app to extend the NTFS partition**.

Better yet would be to use that unallocated space for a swap partition, and enabling swap in /etc/fstab.